# How do I register an event for a button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an HTML document for a javascript file. I want to use a button that will show the drawn rectangle, but I am still don't know fully on how would I code it. This is what my code looks like in HTML document. Also, when I open the html doc in FireFox, it does not show anything beside the title:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Create a document that displays a drawn rectangle -->

<html lang = "en">

<head>
    <title> myRectangle.html </title>
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "myRects.js"
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<h3>Drawing Rectangle</h3>



<form id ="myCanvas" action = "">

<p>

<button> type ="button">Draw Me</button>

</p>

</form>


</body>

</html>
```

This is what the JavaScript file looks like:

```
// myRects.js
// This script shows the use of the rectangle methods of the canvas
// element to draw two rectanges

function draw() {
    var dom = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    if (dom.getContext) {
         var context = dom.getContext('2d');

     // Draw the outer filled rectangle
        context.fillRect(100, 100, 200, 200);

    // Clear a rectangle inside the first rectangle
        context.clearRect(150, 150, 100, 100);

    //Draw a stroke rectange
        context.strokeRect(180, 180, 40, 40);

    //Draw a small filled rectangle
        context.fillRect(195, 195, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: If that's actually how your html is formatted, then I'd consider myself lucky that the title even showed up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason only the title is shown is because you are missing a > after the opening tag of the script in the head: it should be like this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "myRects.js">
</script>
```

to run draw() when the button is clicked, do something like this:

```
<button id="click-to-draw"> Draw me </button>
```

And inside your script (you will need to move the location of the script tag to underneath the button)

```
document.getElementById("click-to-draw").addEventListener("click", function() {
draw();
});
```

**Update**: I just realized that you can simplify this to just 
`document.getElementById("click-to-draw").addEventListener("click", draw);`

Comment: Is this how it should look for HTML: `<p>

<button id="drawRectangle">Draw Me</button>

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "myRects.js">
 </script>

</p>` and also for JavaScript file, I put that line of code, `document.getElementById("click-to-draw").addEventListener("click", function() {
draw();
});` after the last brace for the function draw.

Comment: Almost. The id of the button needs to match the id you use in your js file, so if "drawRectangle" is the id of your button you need to use that in your file, like this: document.getElementById("drawRectangle").addEventListener("click", function() { draw(); })

Comment: Still not getting anything. Whenever I click a button, nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Give your button an id:

```
<button type="button" id="draw-rectangle">Draw Me</button>
```

Add the following code to the end of your JavaScript file to hook the click event up to the draw() function:

```
document.getElementById("draw-rectangle").onclick = draw;
```

And fix your script tag in the head of the document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myRects.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for letting me realize that I was missing an arrow for the opening tag of script. No wonder why nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use the onclick attribute if you want to.

```
<button onclick='draw();'>Draw Me</button>
```